# Passing In Config In Gatling Tests

Tags: scala, gatling, scala-gatling

Noob to Gatling/Scala here.

This might be a bit of a silly question but I haven't been able to find an example of what I am trying to do.

I want to pass in things such as the baseURL, username and passwords for some of my calls. This would change from env to env, so I want to be able to change these values between the envs but still have the same tests in each.

I know we can feed in values but it appears that more for iterating over datasets and not so much for passing in the config values like I have.

Ideally I would like to house this information in a JSON file and not pass it in on the command line, but maybe thats not doable?

Any guidance on this would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a similar setup and you can use pure scala here .In this scenario you can create an object called Config for eg

```
object Configuration {  var INPUT_PROFILE_FILE_NAME = ""; }
```

This class can also read a file , I have the below code in the above object

```
val file = getClass.getResource("data/config.properties").getFile()
val prop = new Properties()
prop.load(new FileInputStream(file));
INPUT_PROFILE_FILE_NAME = prop.getProperty("inputProfileFileName")
```

Now you can import this object in Gattling Simulation File
     val profileName= Configuration.INPUT_PROFILE_FILE_NAME ;

https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/singleton-objects.html.html

Comment: This is perfect! Works exactly as you described. 
Thx